# How to call a static JavaScript method from Blazor C# code

Tags: javascript, c#, interop, blazor

First, my JS:

```
class MyClass {
    static myMethod() {
        alert("TEST");
    }
}
```

I have my JS runtime injected like this:

```
[Inject] protected IJSRuntime Js { get; set; }
```

I want to call a static method like this:

```
Js.InvokeVoidAsync("MyClass.myMethod");
```

but I get an error:

> Microsoft.JSInterop.JSException: Could not find 'MyClass' in 'window'.

Is there a sane, reasonable way around this, or only by adding window.MyClass = MyClass to my JS?

Comment: Nope that's the way to do it. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interop?view=aspnetcore-3.0

Comment: Make a wrapper function in JS that calls the class. This way has it's flaws but when you have a million lines of code left to debug, fast and simple has it's benefits as well.

Answer (score 4):

Try this (assuming server side Blazor).

In your _Host.cshtml file:

```
(function () {
    window.MyClass = {
        myMethod: function () {
            return alert('TEST');
        }
    };
})();
```

in .razor file (at top):

```
@*Inject JSRuntime to allow JavaScript Interop *@
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime
```

In a method in your .razor file:

```
await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<string>(
            "MyClass.myMethod", null
            );
```

See:
[Blazor JavaScript Interop](http://blazorhelpwebsite.com/Blog/tabid/61/EntryId/4317/Blazor-JavaScript-Interop.aspx)

Comment: What is the benefit wrapping it into an IIFE? You still register MyClass into global scope, so the encapsulation is useless, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, registering your method with the window object is correct.

The relevant part of the source code can be found here:

https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions/tree/master/src/JSInterop

Peeking into it you will find:

```
invokeJSFromDotNet: (identifier: string, argsJson: string) => { ... }
```

where

> @param identifier Identifies the globally-reachable function to
>   invoke.

Taking a look at the `findJSFunction` you see the part that checks if the given identifier is registered with the window object and if not generates the error you see:

```
function findJSFunction(identifier: string): Function {

(...)

    let result: any = window;
    let resultIdentifier = 'window';
    let lastSegmentValue: any;
    identifier.split('.').forEach(segment => {
      if (segment in result) {
        lastSegmentValue = result;
        result = result[segment];
        resultIdentifier += '.' + segment;
      } else {
        throw new Error(`Could not find '${segment}' in '${resultIdentifier}'.`);
      }
    });
```

Comment: Hm, classes are reachable via eval, which is not evil when used correctly. I made my own version of "call static" and "create instance" code, I wonder if there is a way to extend JSInterop to use those methods. I mean I made an extension class, but it uses extra JS to work.