# Blazor javascript invoke static class

Tags: javascript, blazor

I have the following javascript statement that declare a static *class* with some static methods:

```
let MyClass = (function() {

MyClass.MyMethod = function(val) {
   // does some stuff
}

})());
```

and in blazor I tried to call

```
await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("MyClass.MyMethod", "some val");
```

but I got error

> Could not find 'MyClass.MyMethod' ('MyClass' was undefined).
> Error: Could not find 'MyClass.MyMethod' ('MyClass' was undefined).
> at https://localhost:XXXXX/_framework/blazor.server.js:1:497

Where is my mistake and how to solve it ?

Comment: try await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("my_function", "some val"); and in js function my_function(message) { console.log("from utilities" + message); } it's the base of functions in js, could be that your jsruntime doesn't recognize your js class?

Comment: I read this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58888300/how-to-call-a-static-javascript-method-from-blazor-c-sharp-code and seems that I can inspire from there

Comment: Have you added the script tag for the js file to your _Host.cshtml (or its equivalent in WASM)? You can check if the file is loaded in your Browser dev tools

Comment: of course I did @noel

Comment: @SnakeEyes please can you test or debug if JSRuntime.invokeVoidAsync actually is calling your javascript file because if that's it the probl;em probably would be another one!